# ionic slide and ionic infinite scroll

Tags: ionic2, infinite-scroll

i want to make a ionic slides and each slides should have a ionic refresher and ionic infinite scroll.

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide>
    <ion-card>
      ...card content
    </ion-card>
    <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="_getNews1($event,from1)" *ngIf="newsType==='news-type-1'">
      <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide>
    <ion-card>
      ...card content
    </ion-card>
    <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="_getNews2($event,from2)" *ngIf="newsType==='news-type-2'">
      <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

But while loading more news from infinite scroll , the slide is not scrolling down and i am unable to see more news at the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

for those looking for just an infinity slides you just need to play with ionSlideReachEnd event for the slides

```
<ion-slides   [options]="sliderOpts" (ionSlideReachEnd)="moreData($event)" >
```

Then In your ts

```
moreData(newData){
  this.offset++;
this.api.post('search/data/'+this.offset,data).toPromise().then((res)=>{
    if (res['status'] == 200) {
      res['oldData'].forEach(newData => {
        this.data.push(newData);
        });

    }})

}
```

and For more UI/UX I think is better  to use ionSlideNextEnd instead

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could leave example code showing how ionSlideReachEnd event could actually be used to solve the ops questions.

Comment: Sorry I didn't noticed your comment here i will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this problem so to wrap the content of ion-slide by ion-content.
But nothing was showed. So I have fixed style of slide-zoom class.

```
<ion-slides>
  <ion-slide>
    <ion-content>
    <ion-card>
      ...card content
    </ion-card>
    <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="_getNews1($event,from1)" *ngIf="newsType==='news-type-1'">
      <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide>
    <ion-content>
    <ion-card>
      ...card content
    </ion-card>
    <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="_getNews2($event,from2)" *ngIf="newsType==='news-type-2'">
      <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>

.slide-zoom{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: so you can have ion-content inside ion-content??

Answer (score 0):

wrap ion-slide's contents with ion-content

```
<ion-slides>
    <ion-slide>
        <ion-content>
            anything what you want
            <ion-infinite-scroll>
            </ion-infinite-scroll>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Comment: i want to have multiple components like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with this simple css:

ion-slides { height: initial; }

this will provide independent scroll to every slide based on it's content.

Answer (score 0):

For Ionic 4

```html
<ion-slides class="slider">
  <ion-slide class="slide" padding *ngFor="let slide of slides">
    <ion-content>
      <h1>{{slide.label}}</h1>  

      <ion-infinite-scroll>
        <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
      </ion-infinite-scroll>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Style

```css
.slider {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem in ionic v3 , i solved it by

```
ion-slides {
  height: auto;
}
```

Referred By https://github.com/brandyscarney